# How can I use Open Liberty dev mode with my Maven WAR project and include JavaScript and CSS files from outside my project (eg from my local machine)?

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

I have some JavaScript and CSS files which are not part of my WAR module source repository.  They are not packaged in a Maven dependency either.  I separately extract them to a path on my local system.

How can I use include these resources in my Maven WAR application and still take advantage of liberty [dev mode](https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/10/22/liberty-dev-mode.html) for rapid, iterative development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include web resources from locations other than the typical **src/main/webapp** directory, configure a property and the maven-war-plugin with the `<webResources>` parameter with something like this:

### pom.xml

```xml
  ...
      <properties>
          <webResDir>/path/to/js-css</webResDir>
      <properties>
  ...
      <build>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${webResDir}</directory>
                       </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <!-- I recommend this config which does a better job of removing any deleted/outdated resources, as of v3.3.2 -->
                    <outdatedCheckPath>/</outdatedCheckPath>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

### NOTES

While the basic idea still applies at earlier versions, you'll get a better experience with recommended minimum versions:

#### PREREQ MINIMUM VERSIONS

- version 3.3.2 of maven-war-plugin *(adds support for outdatedCheckPath syntax shown)*
- version 3.5.2 of liberty-maven-plugin *(adds support for filtered web resources)*

#### PLUGIN-LEVEL CONFIGURATION

Note too the maven-war-plugin configuration **should be added at the plugin level** for liberty dev mode to access it, **rather than at the level of an execution** defined under the maven-war-plugin.

### PROPERTY OVERRIDE

As with Maven project properties in general, this can now be overridden:

- on the command-line:  `mvn -DwebResDir=/some/path ... <goals, phases>`
- In settings.xml (especially useful if you have a host-specific location shared across multiple projects accessed from that system), e.g. see the [Maven Settings documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#properties)

### REFERENCES

More examples here:   https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html